# Reading image files asynchronously and displaying them on the page

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, file-system, express.js

I am trying to display images from a folder in my project using the "fs" module with NodeJS. I need to read all images in a directory and run them in a loop for them to be displayed. I was able to do it but I'm not sure if this is the proper or good way to do it.

I inserted my readdir (Reading Files Asynchronously) inside my Homepage route.
The images were displayed but I have no one to ask if I did it the proper way.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/', function(){ 
    fs.readdir('./assets/images/', (err, files) => {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.render('home', {
            files: files
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should also provide us the `res.render` function

Comment: Hi @konijn, res.render function is from express module required on top, you can check here for reference --> https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render . Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Don't use callbacks, it's hard to read and maintain, the `fs.readdir` function will return a promise if you didn't provide a callback function.
- Use arrow functions when you could.
- Respond with an error instead of throwing (unless you have a catch wrapper middleware).
- Use property shorthands.
- You forgot `req` and `res`.

Try this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => { 
  try {
    const files = await fs.readdir('./assets/images/')
    res.render({ files })  // notice the property shorthand
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ error })
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is cool! Thanks Man very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That's  not a lot to review, but it looks textbook good.

If anything, the value of `'./assets/images/'` could have been an upfront declared constant, or could have been retrieved from a configuration file.

Comment: @konjin Thanks for making time reviewing my code, Your advice is highly appreciated! Thanks again!